# LaTeX and Lyx - modifying a theorem name

Tags: lyx, theorems

I am writing a latex document in French using Lyx. My problem is the following : using the **Theorems (AMS)** Lyx module, I would like the "prop" theorem environment to show up as "Propriété" in my latex document rather than "Proposition".

Is there a simple way for me to modify the "prop" environment in the preamble ?

I know I could simply create a new theorem environment and name it "Propriété", but this would force me to use ERT in Lyx whenever I want to write a new "Propriété", which defeats the purpose of using Lyx (unless someone knows a simple way to modify the Lyx module in order for my "Propriété" environment to show up in the drop-down menu).

I hope my question is clear ! Let me know if it isn't. Basically I want to do the simplest thing possible that would allow me to have a theorem environment in the Lyx drop-down menu that shows up as "Propriété" in the final PDF document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can offer you a relatively easy ERT solution.

The name of the theorem is defined in the variable `\propositionname`, which in English is set as *Proposition*. The standard french translation offered by `babel` is *Proposition*, but you can redefine that by adding (somewhere before you use the first proposition):

```
\renewcommand{\propositionname}{Propriété}
```

The way I see it, if you want a new theorem in your drop-down menu, it would need to be added to the `amsthm` package or at least it's not going to be easy. You could of course try to modify the translation directly in the `babel` package, but I wouldn't recommend that.

Comment: Thank you very much ! This is exactly the type of solution I was looking for.